# Trying to find the exact remaining days in Shell Script $(date +%j)

Tags: linux, shell, date, unix

I am trying this simple script but somehow i get 2 days extra each time:

```
#!/bin/bash
date=$(date +%j)
remaining="$(( 365 - $date))"
echo $remaining
```

On 12/01/2015 i got 355 days remaining whilst it should be 353.

Date and everything's fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The day number is output with a leading zero:

```
$ date +%j
012
```

This means that the number will be interpretted as octal, and octal 012 equals decimal 10 (that's why it's off by 2).  You can manually specify the radix to override the default interpretation:

```
date=$(date +%j)
remaining="$(( 365 - 10#$date))"
echo "$remaining"
```

Gives 353 today, Jan 12.

As a side note, if you want to get the total number of days in the current year instead of hard coding 365, you can use:

```
days_this_year=$(date -d "$(date +%Y)/12/31" +%j)
```

Comment: Whats with leap years? They have 366 days

Comment: `remaining=$((10#$(date -d "Dec 31" +%j) - 10#$(date +%j) ))` -- locale dependent